# how to config basehref for kubernetes dashboard

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, kubernetes-dashboard

The k8s cluster is installed on a host which is only allowed requests through    port 443 from external network. That means all the pods managed by k8s only can be reached through port 443. I installed a Nginx on the host to server reverse proxy to k8s cluster. I installed dashboard and other apps in k8s. The k8s dashboard is exposed with a nodePort 31117. How to config a basehref in k8s dashboard? For example https://ip/dashboard to open the k8s dashboard.

Comment: did you try to expose the port to local with `kubectl proxy`?

Comment: I can access dashboard with nodePort 31117 locally. How to access dashboard outside the host with port 443?

Comment: Please add tag Nginx. This question is more refers to Ngingx. You should find out how to map different andresses map to different PORTS.

Answer (score 2):

You need to set up an upstream in nginx. Since you have exposed it as NodePort -

```
location /dashboard/ {
proxy_pass https://<any-node-ip>:<dashboard-node-port>/;
}
```

You can also look at `Ingress` resource using which you can do the same without hosting your own nginx server.

Comment: Thank you for your solution. I have test it. The index.html can be load but the static resources included can not be loaded since they are using relative path which are mapping to the root.